# `Message No map received` in Rviz

Tags: ros, navigation, rviz, turtlebot-apps, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I try to build a map in Rviz using turtlebot simulation in gazebo. First I create a package and write a launch file which open GAZEBO world and turtlebot in that environment ...

**That is the Launch file**

```
<launch>


 <node name="gazebo" pkg="gazebo" type="gazebo" args="-u $(find gazebo_worlds)/worlds/simple_office.world"/>

 <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true"/>

 <node name="gazebo_gui" pkg="gazebo" type="gui"/>

 <include file="$(find turtlebot_gazebo)/launch/robot.launch"/>

 <include file="$(find turtlebot_teleop)/keyboard_teleop.launch"/>

</launch>
```

Then I run `rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=base_scan _odom_frame:=odom_combined`

Then open Rviz with `rosrun rviz rviz -d 'rospack find turtlebot_navigation' /nav_rviz.vcg` , this command does not open plugins required for gmapping as it can not locate nav_rviz.vcg, so finally I open rviz from launch file

```
<launch>

 <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="$(anon rviz)" args="-d $(find turtlebot_navigation)/nav_rviz.vcg">  </node>

</launch>
```

It work well at lest it run all requirements for gmapping ....

The problem now that when I move robot in gazebo, robot move in rviz too but does not make a map, and I find that massage in rviz : `Message No map received`

**Edit**
I write this command

```
amal@amal-HP-G62-Notebook-PC:~$ rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=base_scan _odom_frame:=odom_combined
```

and nothing else in is written in terminal
[see warning](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/13624221047515495.png)

[All nodes that run and topics](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/13626720472323301.png)

**Edit2**
[That is the map](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/1362771362799174.png)
but I think it will not accurate if there is more details in the environment and It seems to be footprints !!

**Edit3**

Hi, I have a problem now, when I open RVIZ it seem there is a problem in laser scan, map, robot model, and tf [here is](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/13664600851494482.png)

do not know which file I have to check gyro in !!
[That is the error](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/13664595735663573.png)

any suggestion ,
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56998/%60message-no-map-received%60-in-rviz/) by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2013-03-04

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-03-04**:
What is the gmapping output.

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2013-03-04**:
it does not get any output  on rviz

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-03-04**:
I meant the console output.

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2013-03-04**:
I edit the Q

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-03-04**:
Can you check if there is laser data?

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2013-03-04**:
how to do this ?!

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-03-04**:
The simplest way would be an rviz display.

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2013-03-07**:
I edit the Q

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-04-21**:
Please open a new question if a new problem arises.

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2013-04-22**:
OK, Thanks I solve this problem now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Remove the remapping of scan to base_scan. You are publishing the laser on /scan, so no remapping is needed.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2013-03-07**:
sorry I do not understand which remapping ?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-03-07**:
The remapping of scan:=base_scan